# Selenium can't access "bet365 " on a Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-compute-engine, geckodriver

It is known that [www.bet365.com](http://www.bet365.com) implements some kind of bot detection that makes web scraping a bit difficult, but with the help of the Internet I got a Chromedriver configuration for my Python script that let met scrape that website flawlessly in both my Windows 10 host and my local virtualized Ubuntu.

The thing is, I uploaded said script to a GCE Ubuntu virtual machine but Selenium seems to be unable to load this particular website. Every needed package/library is the same as my local linux machine which works fine. **I can get to any other website** with the `driver.get()`  method, is just bet365 the one that keeps loading for around ten seconds and then throws this exception:

```
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

My code is like this:

```
#Chrome Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("headless") 
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows") 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# Avoid detection
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
"source": """

Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {

get: () => undefined

})

"""

})

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride',

{"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

driver.get("https://www.bet365.com")    #<-- Doesn't get past 
time.sleep(3)
print("Website loaded")
```

I also tried with geckodriver without success, which also works with this website on my local VM. Finally, I checked that the site is indeed reachable from the GCE machine with the `curl -Is http://www.bet365.com | head -1` command, returning `200 OK` .

Any idea of what can be the problem here?

Comment: Bet365 has implented something new in the last days. My scripts are not working 1 week ago. =(